# Proof of a Subring

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S$ be a subring of $\mathbb{Z}$. Prove that $S = m\mathbb Z = \{mx \;|\; x ∈ \mathbb Z\}$ for some $m ∈ \mathbb N_0$.

I started by showing that $S$ is non-empty as zero belongs to it. Then I made $x,y$ belong to $S$ and made $x=2a$ and $y=2b$.
Then I showed $x-y$ belonged to $S$ and $xy$ belonged to $S$

Comment: The things you showed need not beshown as they are immediate  consequences (not to say: defining properties) of $S$ being a subring.

Comment: @Saul do you know that $m\mathbb Z$ are the only ideals of $\mathbb Z$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the element $m\in S$ with the smallest nonzero absolute value (if none exist, then $S=0\mathbb Z$). You can then show that every other $n\in S$ is a multiple of $m$ by using the division algorithm to write 
$$
n = mq+r
$$
where $|r|<|m|$. Since $m$ was chosen to have the smallest *nonzero* absolute value, this means that $|r|=0$, so the above is really $n=mq$. Thus, every $n\in S$ is a multiple of $m$, so $S=m\mathbb Z$.